# On Docusaurus, how can I add external link SVG?

Tags: docusaurus

I would like to add an external link logo to links that lead to another site.

[image: link without logo]

I would like to add this logo just to the right of the link :

[image: external link logo]

I haven't found anything in the documentation that would allow me to do this, thank you for your reply.

Comment: do you want to add this logo in header or inside md file?